# Can't grab value from subexpressions

Tags: regex, perl

I'm reading null-separated blocks of data from a socket; upon finding a null, the block read so far is handed for processing, and the buffer is truncated to whatever was left after the null (usually nothing).

```
do {
    $in .= <$sock>
} while(!in =~ /^(.*?)\x00(.*)/) ;
print "A:[ $in, $block ]\n";
$block = $1;
$in = $2;
print "B:[ $in, $block ]";
```

Result:

```
A:[ {"hn":"ITtestKA","v":{"m":4,"u":4}}
,  ]
B:[ ,  ]
```

Why can't I pick the data from the subexpressions `$1`, `$2`?

Comment: `use strict;` `use warnings;` is your friend, and might highlight where there's a massive problem in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another idea is to change the value `$/` which determines how much will `<$sock>` read from `$sock`. So for example, if you do

```
local $/="\0"
```

then for that scope, `<$sock>` will read until the end of the next (null-separated) block.

**Edit**: If the input consists of null-separated blocks, it does not make sense to use `<$sock>` with `$/` having its default value, because then you would be reading the input line by line. So I think there are 2 approaches:

1. Set `$/` to `\0` and use `<$sock>` to read the next block.
2. Read a fixed size chunk and then search for a null byte in it to extract the next block. In this scenario, you can either use `<$sock>` with `$/` set to a reference of the chunk size (e.g. `local $/=\4096`), or use `read`/`sysread`. I would also use `index`/`substr` to search for the null and extract the chunk in that case.

Answer (score 2):

There's a negated form of the binding operator:

```
while($in !~ /^(.*?)\x00(.*)/)
```

Comment: [brian d foy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2766176/brian-d-foy) thanks for the "bug fix".

Answer (score 1):

`in` and `$in` are different things. Do you use [strict](http://p3rl.org/strict)? If not, you're matching `"in"` against the regex and it never matches.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my @socket = ( "abcd\x00efgh",
               "ijkl",
               "mnop\x00qrst",
               "uvwx\x00",
);

my ($in, $block);

while (@socket) {
    do {
        $in .= shift @socket;
    } while ($in !~ /^(.*?)\x00(.*)/) ;
    say "A:[ $in, $block ]";
    ($block, $in) = ($1, $2);
    say "B:[ $in, $block ]";
}
```